# Convert Hash in Array to Hash in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have this Hash in an array:

```
[{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}]
```

I need to convert it to this: a Hash, where each hash has a key of the same date that was contained inside.

```
{"2014-02-12"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, "2014-02-11"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, "2014-02-10"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, "2014-02-09"=> {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's gona happen if two of the hashes have some date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

assign array to variable

```
record = [{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}]
```

and then

```
Hash[record.map { |r| [r['Date'], r] }]
```

result of this is:

```
{"2014-02-12"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, "2014-02-11"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, "2014-02-10"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, "2014-02-09"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data =  [{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}]

data_hash = Hash[data.map{|h| [h['Date'], h]}]
```

And if you do not need the date inside the hash anymore you can do:

```
data_hash = Hash[data.map{|h| [h.delete('Date'), h]}] #=> {"2014-02-12"=>{"All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}...
```

Comment: Fortunately, as sawa pointed out, Array#to_h will replace this ugly usage of Hash[pairs] (but only Ruby >= 2.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}]
.map{|h| [h["Date"], h]}.to_h
```

Comment: @Bala Find it by yourself.

Comment: @Bala It is [Array#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h). `#map` gives us `Array` as a result, on which `to_h` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

first post on stack overflow, here goes nothing - This is a simple answer and doesn't address any special circumstances.  New hash will be stored in the new_hash variable!

```
original_array = [{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}]

new_hash = {}
original_array.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if key == "Date"
        new_hash[value] = hash
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`#index_by` method in ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by):

```
[{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, {"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}].index_by{|h| h["Date"]}
```

Result

```
{"2014-02-12"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-12", "All Installs"=>"7,226", "Bootups"=>"358,439"}, "2014-02-11"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-11", "All Installs"=>"7,759", "Bootups"=>"383,873"}, "2014-02-10"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-10", "All Installs"=>"7,958", "Bootups"=>"286,067"}, "2014-02-09"=>{"Date"=>"2014-02-09", "All Installs"=>"9,439", "Bootups"=>"331,402"}}
```